# Revolution Slider stuck at loading

Tags: media, javascript

I need your help. I am running a site (D7.43, jQuery 1.10) with the Jollyany theme under the hood. The theme comes packaged with the revolution Slider from ThemePunch. I am trying to include a slider into a page, but am then confronted with the slider being empty and the loading spinner spinning away merrily forever. Navigation bullets and left right arrows are visible but do nothing.

You can see the page here: wixschool.net/test-class.

This page shows the revolution slider in place. The slider shows the last of three images, constant spinner, no transition to next slide. Navigation also doesn't go anywhere, slider completely stuck. Slider scripts are called in the head, html for the slider is put in place and seems OK.

(In fact the sldier does not even show any picture, but I've removed the 'visiblity hidden" from the CSS of the background image so its easier to see the slider.. and it then shows the last of three images, not the first..)

There were suggestions out there that it may be (double call to) script issue, so I have tried switching off all other scripts that are called in the head  and below the body to see if that would make a difference, but besides losing functionaltiy that those scripst supply the slider stays stuck..

Any suggestions as to why the slider doesn't work is extremely welcome!

Edit: I just noticed that on the test-class page the TB MegaMenu dropdown in the menu don't work (any other page they do..). Tried removing the entire menu as well as the TB Menu scripts but still no working slider..

Comment: I see [two errors](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7LnXU.jpg)

Comment: Thanks! yes I saw those too, don't know how to correct those scripts though.. I did try just removing them altogether (no idea what countdown or hammer .js do), made no difference to the site but slider still not working..

Comment: If a site throws JavaScript errors all scripts block on that page. So the errors prevent the slider (and the menu) from working. You can try to install the theme on a vanilla site (no other modules), have a look at http://simplytest.me if it doesn't work either, check the theme (or module?) issue queue for a solution or report the bug there. 
If it does work on a vanilla website it might be an incompatibility with another module and then there is little we can do.

Comment: In `hammer.js` It appears to me that line 168 needs to be `addEventListeners` with an **s** and line 180 needs to be `removeEventListeners` also with an **s** at the end.

Comment: I've tried adding the two s's, now still get an error about line 168, saying that `target.addEventListeners` is not defined? The hammer.js script is called by the menu (the mobile menu) and the revolution slider both (the hammer.js is included in the jQuery.themepunch.plugins.min.js)

Comment: Have been playing around, it is clearly the hammer.js issue, during one fiddle I did get the revolution slider to work, but then errors came back. I tried renaming all  `EventListener` items in hammer to `EventListeners` and also the reverse, but whatever the name get the warning the function `EventListener(s)` doesn't exist. Also tried removing the hammer bit from the slider plugin js, but that didn't help either. I'll report back if I find out more! Thanks for the help and pointers.

Comment: Interesting note: the hammer.js error does not appear on any other pages even thought that script is called everywhere; so I assume it must be that the `EventListener` handle is used twice (once for the menu and once for the rev slider?) and thus clashes?

Comment: Thanks for all your pointers. Disable the hammer.js script from the mmenu module and bingo, Revolution slider works like a charm :) no-sssweat, if you put that in a proper answer I can give you a vote up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason for Revolution Slider failure found: the Rev Slider uses the `hammer.js` jQuery plugin. Elsewhere on my site I have installed the jQuery mMenu, which also has `hammer.js` among its scripts. I disabled `hammer.js` in mmenu, and the Rev Slider comes alive immediately. The clash centres around the `event listeners` functions in the hammer script.

Haven't solved all though, mmenu still works fine but I do get a 'where is hammer.js' error thrown at me now of course. Will report when and how I solve that..